# Jetpack Compose override theme in an application for components from a library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme

What is the proper way to override theme/style for components from a library in Jetpack Compose? I will try to simplify this and show my current idea of how the problem can be solved.

In my project, I have library with composable in this composable there is a `Text` and I want this `Text` to have a different style in the library and in the app. What I did is to define values in the `res` folder in the library and then override these values in my application `res` folder. In the end, I created `TextStyle` and then applied it to the `Text`. It looks like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyText()
{
    val myTextStyle = TextStyle(
        color = colorResource(id = R.color.textColor),
        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.montserrat_semibold))
    )
    Text(
        text = "Some text",
        style = myTextStyle
    )
}
```

This works but I think it is not the best way of doing this, and what's more, changing the font is hard because I have to have two different fonts with the same name.

Comment: What would be recommended, is to create your own theme. Yes, it is entirely possible to have more than one theme in the project.